# How to prevent OnSelectedIndexChanged to cause postback unless the user uses the mouse or the enter key?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

here's a dropdownlist that posts back on selected index changed.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlClientType" runat="server"  AutoPostBack = "true"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ClientType_SelectedIndexChanged"  >                                 
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="CANCEL.."></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="External"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="Internal"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="13" Text="TOM"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

When using the mouse, everything works perfectly. However, I want user to be able to press key to select different items either by by using up/down arrow key. Also when when user type a letter, then the first item starting with that letter gets highlighted.

The problem is when a different item gets selected in the dropdownlist, the page posts back because of the "**OnSelectedIndexChanged**" event.

Is there a way to prevent the postback to occur when key are being pressed (as opposed to mouse being clicked), until the **enter key** is pressed?

## EDIT

I'm able to display the alert prompt when a key is pressed

```
$('select').keypress(function () {
  alert('A key was pressed')
});
```

Now, I need to know which key was pressed. Thus, I'll be able to make a decision.

Comment: To know the key pressed us `e.which` e must be passed throught `function(e)...`

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault();` or `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent postback to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of a mistake in your question:

> The problem is when a different item gets selected in the dropdownlist, the page posts back because of the "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event.

The page is actually posting back because of `AutoPostBack = "true"`.

First change AutoPostBack to False.

Then I would suggest that you handle the change event and the keypress event differently. If you handle the change event using jQuery and then submit inside that change event and also handle the keydown and filter for keys then you can submit only when you want to.

```
$("#TargetSelect").change(function(event){
    console.debug($(this).val());
});
$("#TargetSelect").keydown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  if(event.which == 13){
     $(this).trigger('change');
  }else if(event.which == 38){
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    if(idx != 0){
      $("#TargetSelect").prop('selectedIndex', idx-1); 
    }
  }else if(event.which == 40){
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    var maxIndex = $('select').children('option').length;
    idx += 1;           
    if(idx < maxIndex){
      $("#TargetSelect").prop('selectedIndex', idx); 
    }
  }else{
      var $options = $('select').children('option');
      $options.each(function(){
        if(String.fromCharCode(event.which) == $(this).text().charAt(0)){
          var idx = $(this).index();
          $("#TargetSelect").prop('selectedIndex', idx);     
        }
      });
    }
});
```

[Here is an (updated) example](http://jsfiddle.net/cHpNe/4/). Replace the console.debug with submit of the form and you should be golden.

If you have multiple select boxes the code should be as follows:

```
$("select").change(function(event){
    console.debug($(this).val());
});
$("select").keydown(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  if(event.which == 13){
     $(this).trigger('change');
  }else if(event.which == 38){
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    if(idx != 0){
      $(this).prop('selectedIndex', idx-1); 
    }
  }else if(event.which == 40){
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;
    var maxIndex = $(this).children('option').length;
    idx += 1;           
    if(idx < maxIndex){
      $(this).prop('selectedIndex', idx); 
    }
  }else{
      var $options = $(this).children('option');
      var $thisSelect = $(this);
      $options.each(function(){
        if(String.fromCharCode(event.which) == $(this).text().charAt(0)){
          var idx = $(this).index();
          $thisSelect.prop('selectedIndex', idx);     
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Also be aware that if you have two entries that start with the letter typed, then you will select the last entry. A modification could be made to the code to allow for the box to be filtered.

[Example for multiple boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/cHpNe/9/)

Comment: The last option is not working properly. When I press a key, all the dropdownlist have their selectedindex modified instead of the index of the sole alement that has the focus.

Comment: This was a wickedly under simplified example. I was using 'select' as the selector because I only had one in the example. You need to select by ID or by class name. I will update it for multiple select boxes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I kept the autopostback to true and ignore the first statement. It's working they way I wanted

Answer (score 1):

If you use the onblur event, it will postback when the dropdown loses focus.

Comment: Actually, I want to control the postback action. I want to know what was the user's action. If the index changed because of the mouse click then the postback can occur. However, if the the index changed because the user pressed some key, for instance the up or down key, then prevent the postback from occuring (unless the user press the "enter" key). In other terms, only a mouse click and the "enter" key should be allow to cause the postback.